# Twitter4J - Running android user stream listener as (background) service

Tags: java, android, service, twitter4j

I have implemented twitter4j's user stream listener (3.0.6 snapshot) as a service (running on boot and user present) and the code works fine, but in my android app I've the problem with randomly closing stream.
The exception 420 is thrown: "Running too many copies of the same application authentication with the same account name".
Is there a way to fix this, or is this an general problem, because users with different IPs have to login with the same credentials in one twitter application?
There are about 40 users running my app...

Here is my code:

**TwitterConnectionManager.java**

```
public class TwitterConnectionManager {

    private static final String TAG = TwitterConnectionManager.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String TWITTER_USER = "";

    public static final String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "";
    public static final String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "";
    public static final String TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN = "";
    public static final String TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "";

    private static Twitter instance = null;
    private static Configuration conf = null;
    private static Authorization auth = null;

    public static Twitter getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = getTwitterConnection();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public TwitterConnectionManager() {

    }

    public static Twitter getTwitterConnection() {
        authorize();
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance(auth);
        return twitter;
    }

    private static void authorize() {
        try {       
            ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            cb.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
            cb.setOAuthAccessToken(TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN);
            cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

            if (conf == null) {
            conf = cb.build();
            if (auth == null) {
                auth = AuthorizationFactory.getInstance(conf);
            }
            }       
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Error authenticate Twitter: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    public static TwitterStream getTwitterStreamConnection(UserStreamListener listener) {
        TwitterStream ts = getTwitterStreamConnection();
        ts.addListener(listener);
        return ts;
    }

    public static TwitterStream getTwitterStreamConnection() {
        authorize();
        TwitterStream ts = new TwitterStreamFactory().getInstance(auth);
        return ts;
    }
}
```

**TwitterService.java**

```
public final class TwitterService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = TwitterService.class.getSimpleName();

    private static NotificationManager notificationManager = null;
    private static SharedPreferences prefs = null;
    private static AudioManager audioManager = null;
    private static TwitterStream twitterStream = null;

    private static ConnectThread connectThread = null;
    //private Twitter twitter = null;
    static final long MILLISECOND = 1000;

    public class MyServiceLocalBinder extends Binder {
        TwitterService getService() {
            return TwitterService.this;
        }
    }

    private final IBinder mBinder = new MyServiceLocalBinder();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int StartId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting twitter service");

        if (!isConnected()) {
            connectThread = new ConnectThread();
            connectThread.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onUnbind");
        twitterStream.shutdown();
        super.onUnbind(intent);
        stopSelf();
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        if (connectThread != null && twitterStream != null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopSelf();
        twitterStream.shutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // ***** ONLY for debugging *****//
        // android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

        // Get the system parameters
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void setNotification(String txt) {
        // Check the common preferences for notification
        if (prefs.getBoolean("ckbPrefNotify", true)) {
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
            mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.appName));
            mBuilder.setContentText(txt);

            // Get ringer mode
            int ringerMode = audioManager.getRingerMode();

            // Check sound preferences
            if (ringerMode == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL && prefs.getBoolean("ckbPrefSoundNotify", false) == true) {
            playSound();
            }

            // Check vibration preferences
            if (ringerMode != AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT && prefs.getBoolean("ckbPrefVibrationNotify", false) == true) {
            long[] pattern = { 0, 200, 80, 800, 80, 200, 80, 200 };
            mBuilder.setVibrate(pattern);
            }

            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);

            notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }

    private void playSound() {
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = null;
        try {
            descriptor = this.getAssets().openFd("sounds/owl_01.mp3");
            mp.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
            descriptor.close();
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio file: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.start();
    }

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            if (twitterStream != null) {
            twitterStream.cleanUp();
            twitterStream.shutdown();
            twitterStream = null;
            }
            startStreaming();
        }
    }

    private void startStreaming() {
        // Get the stream
        twitterStream = TwitterConnectionManager.getTwitterStreamConnection();
        if (twitterStream != null) {
            // Add the listeners
            twitterStream.addListener(new MyUserStreamAdapter());
            try {
            Log.i(TAG, "Start connectStream() for twitterStream.user()");
            twitterStream.user();
            } 
            catch (java.lang.IllegalStateException illstaex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ConnectThread connectStream() IllegalStateException illstaex=" + illstaex);
            connectThread = null;
            twitterStream = null;
            }
        } 
        else {
            Log.e(TAG, "ConnectThread connect() got no twitter stream");
            connectThread = null;
        }
    }

    private class MyUserStreamAdapter extends UserStreamAdapter {   
        @Override
        public void onStatus(Status status) {
            super.onStatus(status);
            if (status.getUser().getScreenName().equalsIgnoreCase(TwitterConnectionManager.TWITTER_USER)) {
            String text = status.getText();
            Log.i(TAG, "onStatus(): " + text);
            setNotification(status.getText());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Each user using your app should have their own tokens, don't share the token across multiple instances.

Comment: Is it possible to get the tokens without user interaction and without logging into twitter with the users' account?
I want to share the streaming messages to users who have no twitter account.

Comment: No. You need to have a user account to do this. The only way around is to use a proxy server which serves the data to your app from your own account.